# Android Studio has a very buggy attribute window when using search bar

Tags: android-studio

So when I try to use the attribute window on Android Studio and wanted to search for something for my text or button it will be very buggy after I click away and click on something else like an Image, it will just keep that inputted search I previously used even though I have removed it.

So far I tried:

1- Restarting Android Studio.

2 - Invalidate Caches.

3 - Tried other PC same problem.

I am using Windows 10 - 64 bit with the latest Android Studio 3.3.2

https://youtu.be/KZrJltsnQL8

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding and cleaning the project.